# Python selenium webdriver error: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Options

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have this simple piece of code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

options = EdgeOptions()
options.use_chromium = True
options.headless = True

print('- Finish importing packages')

driver = webdriver.Edge(options)
```

Running this gives me the error:

```
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Options
```

What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge
from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

print('- Finish importing packages')

edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.use_chromium = True
edge_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = Edge(executable_path="C:\python\msedgedriver.exe",  options=edge_options)
```